# Windows Security asking for user name and password

Tags: windows-7, security

I have a issue where on a Windows 7 AD machine where it is constantly asking for proxy user name and password. We enter the information and it is accepted, then an hour or two later it asks again. The user is complaining that it is very annoying. I have cleared the user name and password stored in Windows but it is still asking.

Comment: Proxy in AD? Proxy product name and version?

Comment: Microsoft Firewall ISA Server not sure what version.

Comment: Is this after screen-saver has kicked in? If so, does security at your location require password afterwards?

Comment: This happens whenever it feels like. I would be in the middle of working in Excel and it it pops up or if I am browsing the Internet. I cannot duplicate the issue manually. Only happens to one user. I reset the default on the TSA client and made sure it was set to auto config.